# Custome notification sound is playing only if i have breakpoint windows universal 8.1

Tags: push-notification, toast, win-universal-app

Hi when push notification is received i am displaying toast notification. i have issue that  is if i have break point in below function then and then only custom notification sound is playing else notification sound is not playing.I thought might be audio is not loading so i added Task.delay for 2 sec/5 sec but no luck.  What could be the issue..

```
        public static void AddTostNotification(String xmlDocument)
    {

       List<string> messageSection = PushNotificationHelper.GetMessageAndLandingPage(xmlDocument);

       ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText01;

        XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);
        XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(messageSection[0]));
      //  toastTextElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(message));

        IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
        ((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("launch", messageSection[1]);

        XmlElement audio = toastXml.CreateElement("audio");
        audio.SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///Assets/Guitar.wav");

        toastNode.AppendChild(audio);

        //launch tost immediatly
        ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i got it, It was threading issue,

```
        //var ignored = dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        //{

                PushNotificationHelper.AddTostNotification(notificationContent);


        //});
```